# PHP/Symfony, keep entire data's from DB

Tags: php, database, symfony, format

In my database, i have french departement(TINYTEXT) :

[image]

When i get the data, PHP format my code and remove the first 0 when the code start with 0.
And remove letter when the code ends with a letter (2A or 2B)

For the first 0 i tried :

```
sprintf("%02d", $dep->getCode())
```

Thats work but, not for the ending letter.

So, for the letter i tried with:

```
str_contains($checkDep[0]->getcode(), "a")
```

But, doesn't work.I've tried with VARCHAR instead of TINYTEXT

It's possible to keep the entire data without PHP/Symfony formating ?

thx.

Comment: The `d` in `sprintf` is a decimal digit, so letters would be dropped. I'm guessing that your `getCode` method is somehow converting it to an int, can you post the contents of that method?

Comment: Ok, thx a lot @ChrisHaas. After your message, i've changed in my entity : #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)] for #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)] and now it's ok !thansk a lot.

Answer (score 0):

ok, after @Chris Haas Message, i'v changed in my entity :

```
 #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)]
```

for :

```
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
```

And thats work.